# structure is not copying to other struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, scanf

So, I have this struct:

```
typedef struct person {
   char *name;
   int age;
   struct person* next;
}
```

I also have my hash_table:

```
person *table[50];
```

I have a function that gets the variables I want to use:

```
void add_person() {
   person *new_person = (person*) malloc(sizeof(new_person));
   char str1[50];
   int age;
   scanf(" %[^:\n]:%d",str1,&age);
   new_person->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(str1)+1)*sizeof(char));
   strcpy(new_person->name,str1);
   new_person->age =age;
   printf("%s %d",new_person->name,new_person->age) //checking if struct variables change (they do)
   insert_hash_table(new_person);
   free(new_person);
   free(new_person->name);   
 }
```

Here it is my insert_hash_table(person *p) that adds an element to my hash table:

```
void insert_hash_table(person *p) {
    int index = hash(p->name); //hash function
    p->next = table[index];
    table[index] = p;
    printf("%s",table[index]->name); //just to check if the struct was copied
 }
```

But when I type this input:

```
Josh:35
```

It dosen´t print "Josh" which was suposed to because of this command:

```
printf("%s",table[index]->name)
```

Any suggestions? I would be thankful for any help you could give.

Comment: `person *new_person = (person*) malloc(sizeof(new_person));` should be `sizeof(*new_person)`.

Comment: `free(new_person); free(new_person->name);`. That shouldn't be done because the hash table has stored those pointers. By freeing them the memory is no longer valid and hence the hash table contains invalid pointers.

Comment: `free(new_person); free(new_person->name);` is bad even if `insert_hash_table` were copying the data instead of storing the pointer directly because `free(new_person->name);` is accessing pointer that is already freed by `free(new_person);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_person` allocates a `person` and its `name`, but `insert_hash_table` does not copy the data, it merely references it. Consequently, after the data was freed in `add_person`, it is not accessible anymore. Also, the deallocation order is incorrect. The `name` has to be freed first as its pointer is stored in `person`. Only then, `person` can be deallocated.

Besides changing the deallocation order, you have to make an actual copy in `insert_hash_table`. You can do so by allocating another `person`, copy the person by dereferencing both pointers to trigger a shallow copy (*hashtable_person = *person) and copy the name using `strdup`.

I'm not sure what the `next` field represents, though. `next` implies a singly-linked list, but the code does not remember the last inserted person to be able to create one.

In this specific case, it might be simpler to just pass the ownership of `person` on to the hash table by calling `insert_hash_table`. Then you can allocate the `person`, but do not have to worry about deallocation. Removing the `person` from the hash table could either trigger a deallocation or - to be consistent - you could pass the ownership back to the caller in that case.